I want to console log the entire form data after gravity form submission
i was tryting with this code but this is not working
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, form_id) {
        if (form_id === 3) { // Replace 3 with your actual form ID
            var formData = jQuery('#gform_3').serializeArray(); // Replace 3 with your actual form ID

            // Log the full form data
            console.log('Full Form Data:', formData);
        }
    });
});


That event is only for AJAX-enabled forms, and fires when the confirmation message is displayed, at which point, the fields likely no longer exist (source).

@Caleb is right, this event only applies for ajax forms. By the time this event fires your submission data is all gone.
However.. you could be sneaky and save the submission data to local storage which would work for either situation.. ajax or non ajax gforms :-)
Make sure you add this all in your jQuery doc ready function...
// first listen for your form submission
$('#gform_3').on('submit', function(e) {

  // temporally prevent form from submitting on submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // lets get the form data as serialised array
  let formData = $(this).serializeArray();

  // set an empty form object (so we can log as an 1 object later)
  let formObj = {};

  // loop thru our form data and add them to our form object
  $.each(formData, function(i, field) {

    // add by key name and field value to object
    formObj[field.name] = field.value;

  });

  // now lets be sneaky and save to local storage temporally 
  localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formObj));

  // now let finish what we started and submit the form!
  this.submit();

});

Ok thats handled saving the form data to local storage before submitting but then submitting after form data is saved.
So immediately after this in the same jQuery doc ready function add this below, which gets our local storage form data on page load...
// get our saved form data
let savedFormData = localStorage.getItem('formData');

// if we got form data
if(savedFormData) {

  // parse the saved form data back to object
  let formDataObj = JSON.parse(savedFormData);

  // then lets console log this form submission...
  console.log(formDataObj);

  // then lets remove the local storage form data but not really needed as this will override everytime, but removing keeps tidy I guess.
  localStorage.removeItem('formData');

}

OK if your Gravity Form is ajax loaded on your page, you can use this as a fallback to load on the confirmation event anyway, just include this after the the code above
// fallback gform confirmation event to still log the message if the page does not refresh
jQuery(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, form_id) {

  // taken from you code to only hit form id 3
  if (form_id === 3) { // Replace 3 with your actual form ID

    // get our saved form data
    let savedFormData = localStorage.getItem('formData');

    // if we got form data
    if(savedFormData) {

      // parse the saved form data back to object
      let formDataObj = JSON.parse(savedFormData);

      // then lets console log this form submission...
      console.log(formDataObj);

      // then lets remove the local storage form data but not really needed as this will override everytime, but removing keeps tidy I guess.
      localStorage.removeItem('formData');

    }

  }

});

This is not tested but i'm sure this will get you on the right track to consoling the form submission of gravity form id, in either normal mode or ajax mode.
Good luck!
